# Returning an array of interface instances

Tags: java, jaxb, glassfish, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am working on a small project where I have to return an array of instances of a specific interface. When I return a single instance of the interface, everything works fine. When I return an array of instances, I get the following error :

---

**Edit August 2nd, 2013** 
*The same code works perfectly if I use abstract classes. Interfaces seem to be the problem.*

---

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of             IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Person is an interface and JAXB cannot handle interfaces 
       est une interface et JAXB ne peut pas gérer les interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
    at Person
Person does not have a default empty constructor 
       ne comporte aucun constructeur sans argument par défaut.
    this problem is related to the following location:
    at Person
```

How to I handle returning an array of instances of an interface using JAXB and JAX-RS?

I am using Gassfish 4, and tried the following. Data code:

```
@XmlRootElement
public interface Person {
  @XmlAttribute
  public String getId();
  @XmlElement
  public String getName();
}

@XmlRootElement
public class P1 implements Person {

  @Override
  @XmlAttribute
  public String getId() {
    return "1";
  }

  @Override
  @XmlElement
  public String getName() {
    return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
  }
}

@XmlRootElement
public class P2 implements Person {

  @Override
  @XmlAttribute
  public String getId() {
    return "2";
  }

  @Override
  @XmlElement
  public String getName() {
    return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
  }
}
```

JAX-RS code :

```
Person[] persons = {new P1(), new P2()};

@GET
@Path("/query")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Person[] findByQuery(@QueryParam("name") String name) {
  return persons;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you add a default empty constructor to the `P1` and `P2` classes (`P1() { super(); }`)?

Comment: @drvdijk Thank you for your reply. I have the same exception raised when I add a default empty constructor to the P1 and P2 classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try pointing at the implementation classes from your interface class, like:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({P1.class, P2.class})
public interface Person {
  @XmlAttribute
  public String getId();
  @XmlElement
  public String getName();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I tried and the same exception is raised.

Comment: The same code works perfectly if I use abstract classes. Interfaces seem to be the problem. Do you know JAX-B can handle array of interfaces?